# can i approve the pull request after some days in github

Tags: git, github

I received a pull request into the development branch from the feature branch. the PR is not merged for 1 day, now I want to merge it but I can see other admins added a lot of new changes in the development branch. if I approve the PR now, will I lose the newly added changes in development?

Answer (score 1):

A "pull request" is not a feature of git, it's a feature of certain git hosts like github or bitbucket.

It sounds like your question is actually about merging, specifically if in this situation

```
>-A---D---E->
   \     /
    B---C
```

where E is a merge commit, will the changes from C safely integrate with those from D?

In general, there is no clear answer. Git performs a "three-way merge" by analyzing how to the branches have diverged from their common ancestor A and tries to detect cases where they conflict. If it detects conflicts, it won't let you merge until you manually resolve them by merging D into C.

But even when git doesn't detect conflicts, there can still be issues, for example if D and C both affect common logic but don't actually touch the same code. Git likely won't detect the problem automatically.

In general the safest thing would be to first merge D into C (in your case, merge develop into your feature branch) or rebase your feature branch onto D. Either way, you'll probably want to retest the changes on your feature branch to ensure that nothing broke when incorporating D.